# Can I fabricate a PCB using this schematic?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, schematic

I am a newbie to schematic and electric circuit design. This is one of my first schematics and I am thinking of making a PCB out of this one.

I want to ensure my PCB will work after fabrication. It uses an ATmega328P as microcontroller and also has an MLX sensor, an LCD and an ultrasonic sensor.

I have attached the schematic with this post.

Please give me suggestions if you have any. I want to know whether my PCB will work or not if I fabricate it using this schematic.

[image: SCHEMATIC IMAGE]

Comment: It hard to say if a PCB design works or not by just looking at the schematic, even if the schematic is right in all aspects. It totally depends on the layout.

Comment: the schematic is missing decoupling capacitor for the MCU

Comment: Ah, your circuit uses UART and SPI interface for ultrasonic sensor and LCD. If you limit to low speed, say UART 9600bd8n1 and SPI 400kHz, and if your prototype on a breadboard works OK, then there is a high chance that it would also work on a PCB

Comment: Please clarify your question: Do you want us to check your schematic or do you want to know if you can give such schematic to a PCB assembly factory to produce the PCB?

Comment: You have only put the schematics here without describing how do you expect it to work. Why is the LCD contrast pin driven from MCU, how do you think it will work? Why is the LCD backlight directly connected to 5V and GND without current limiting, as not all LCD backlights work like that? Why are you limiting to 4-bit without being able to read busy from LCD? Should there be pull up or pull down resistors for the buses, as those seem to be using I2C and SPI?

Comment: maybe needs a transistor to switch current through SG1

Comment: What are the “Programmer” connections for? Are they not just USART RX/TX?

Comment: Make sure you're feeding enough voltage into U1 to get 5 volts out. You'll lose some voltage across D1 and more voltage across the unspecified regulator (maybe two volts for a 7805 and less if it's a low dropout regulator). As an aside, the power schematic drawing would be clearer if you drew it with power in on the left, power out on the right and ground on the bottom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No one can tell you for sure if it will work.  It probably won't.

Too many of your parts don't have model numbers.

- VR1 appears to be a 5V regulator. Which one?  Without a datasheet or at least a part number, no one can tell you if you have it connected properly and have used the correct input and output capacitor types and values.
- You have some unknown LCD in the circuit, and have not connected half of the data lines.  Maybe that's correct for your LCD, but I doubt it.
- You have a buzzer connected directly to the microprocessor.  That probably won't work well since microprocessor pins can only deliver a few milliamperes of current.  Maybe your buzzer would work.  Nobody knows - no datasheet or model number.
- What is U1?  No model numbe or anything else.  No one can tell you if it is connected correctly.
- Which MLX sensor?  They make many.  No model number, no datasheet.
- Which ultrasound sensor?  No model, no datasheet, no idea.

You have no decoupling capacitors at all for the microprocessor.  Sometimes (when the stars align and the monks in a temple somewhere mutter the proper incantations) that works.  Sometimes it works well enough that you think it is fine - until it suddenly doesn't work and you can't see any reason for it to have changed.

If you made a PCB from this circuit, it might do something but it probably won't work as you intended it to.

Comment: From the picture the LCD is a jellybean HD44780, for which connecting only the low nibble of the data lines is common practice (4-bit mode). But I agree that the provided diagram is more on the level of a fritzig diagram for a hobbyist than a professional circuit diagram.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen:  The LCD model you name may be correct, but in that case it will **not** work since the lower bits aren't connected.

Comment: Good catch with the buzzer. Does it require DC to turn it on/off or does it require driving it with the actual tone? The LCD data connections are just fine for 4-bit mode, but it makes little sense to use non-contiguous MCU pins for the data bus - it will work but most HW and SW people would just think why it is so awkward. The LCD enable pin would benefit from pull-down so it does not require extra software work for initializing it from any random state.

Comment: @JRE All HD44780 compatible modules which are the most common modules available since 80's can use 4-bit mode as it is drawn. It does not require 8-bit data bus.

Comment: @JRE: 1,$s/low/high